# Why can't I read the $stateParams of a nested state with Angular-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My route definition is:

```
$stateProvider.state("passages", {
  abstract: true,
  url: "/passages",
  controller: "PassageController",
  template: "<div ui-view></div>"
}).state("passages.list", {
  url: "/list",
  templateUrl: "/views/passages/list.html"
}).state("passages.upsert", {
  url: "/upsert/:passageId",
  templateUrl: "/views/passages/upsert.html"
});
```

And in my `PassageController`, I have `console.log $stateParams.passageId`, and it goes to undefined. The URL I hit is `http://localhost:3000/passages/upsert/myId`

Comment: have you tried  these things. 
are you able to access on outer state? can you also provide controller code.
can you explicitly set controller for 'passages.upsert'

Comment: it's posssible to read `passageId` only in `passages.upsert` state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**it's only possible** to read **$stateParams** property in state where it is defined.

Comment: Can you clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

i could be wrong but your child states don't extend the url of the parent state. the abstract parent state url is simply a default which a child will inherit if no url is defined for a child.
try defining the urls in your child states as ...

```
url: "/passages/list"
```

AND

```
url: "/passages/upsert/:passageId"
```

Comment: I believe a child state inherits from the `parent`. The URLs do load, the state param simply doesn't get passed.

Comment: i didnt say a child state does not inherit from the parent. please read more carefully